# How to remove the unwanted barcode characted (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

I ran into an obstacle and would like to ask for your help.

How can I solve it that not to show the all scanned characters in textbox.

Original scanned data

```
P338-7755885BP0097170824
```

Necessary data (that's what I want to display in textbox)

```
338-7755885
```

[image]

Comment: What are the rules so it selects those numbers?  Is it from end of first alpha string to start of next?  Three characters before hyphen and seven after?

Comment: Thanks, but managed to solve.                                                   
                                                                                                    
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Me.TextBox1.MaxLength = 24

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    If Len(TextBox1.Text) = TextBox1.MaxLength Then
    TextBox1.Value = Mid(TextBox1.Value, 2, 11)
    
    End If

End Sub

Comment: @Norbulus you can post it as an answer (instead of a comment) and after waiting a day you can accept your own answer as solution.